# Why replaceAll method not available in StringBuilder

Tags: java

I am doing code scanning using sonarQube. I found issue **Introduce a new variable instead of reusing the parameter "value"**. 
should I use StringBuilder instead of String or introducing a new variable? Below is my code.

```
private String stripXSS(String value) {

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {

            value = value.replaceAll("", "");

            Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

            value = value.replace("&", "&amp;");
            value = value.replace(">", "&gt;");
            value = value.replace("<", "&lt;");
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the connection between your title and the content of your question. Please clarify, what is the actual problem?

Comment: StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder(value);
builder.replaceAll("", ""); //  replaceAll method not available.

Comment: Which is fine, but what does that have to do with the sonarQube error you got, which tells you not to reuse a parameter but create a local variable instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your part of the question that **should I use StringBuilder instead of String or introducing a new variable ?**

The following is the **comparison between the String, StringBuffer and StringBuilder**... You should use according to your need... i.e. Memory, performance, etc.

```
                  String                    StringBuffer         StringBuilder

Storage Area | Constant String Pool    |       Heap         |           Heap
Modifiable   |  No (immutable)         |   Yes( mutable )   |      Yes( mutable )
Thread Safe  |     Yes                 |       Yes          |             No
 Performance |   Fast                  |    Very slow       |            Fast
```

Answer (score 0):

Would following slightly changed code of yours not solve your problem? Just don't overly operate on the passed value and instead create a new local String variable that is used throughout your method! Performance optimizations need not considered (String vs. StringBuilder) as of now unless your supervisor wants faster code. Or implement (Thread.sleep(1000)) for future optimization endeavours ;-)

```
private String stripXSS(String passedValue) {

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(passedValue)) {

        String value = passedValue.replaceAll("", "");

        Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("eval\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("expression\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("javascript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("vbscript:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onload(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");

        value = value.replace("&", "&amp;");
        value = value.replace(">", "&gt;");
        value = value.replace("<", "&lt;");
    }
    return value;
}
```